# How to combine options to produce number of possible configurations total?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to solve this combinatorial problem:

> A certain company sells jellybeans in the following six flavors only:
>   banana, chocolate, grape, lemon, peach, and strawberry. The jellybeans
>   are sorted randomly into boxes, and one-third of the boxes have
>   exactly 2 different flavors, one-third of the boxes have exactly 3
>   different flavors, and one-third of the boxes have exactly 4 different
>   flavors. What is the probability that any given box contains grape
>   jellybeans?

I'm trying to compute it by determining the fraction of number of ways to choose grape, over total number of outcomes.  In my answer, the denominator combines these options like so:

$$\frac{5+C(5,2)+C(5,3)}{C(6,2)*C(6,3)*C(6,4)}$$

But in the answer it looks like this

$$\frac{5+C(5,2)+C(5,3)}{C(6,2)+C(6,3)+C(6,4)}$$

Why is the denominator added instead of multiplied?  For each choice of the boxes, there are multiple choices for the others, if I'm understanding correctly, right?

Comment: I don't understand either of these expressions.  If I understand the problem properly (far from certain) then if you get a two flavor box there is a $\frac 13$ chance of getting grape, a $\frac 12$ chance if you get a three flavor box, and a $\frac 23$ chance if you get a four flavor box.  Thus the answer is $\frac 13\times \left(\frac 13+\frac 12+\frac 23\right)=\frac 12$.  Am I misreading the problem?

Comment: Neither your answer nor the stated answer are correct.  Please check to see if you transcribed the stated answer correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I actually mis-typed the question.  It is $C(5,3)$ instead of $C(6,4)$.  Sorry about that!  Fixing it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither your answer nor the stated answer are correct.

Let $G$ be the event that a box containing grape-flavored jellybeans is selected.  Let $2, 3, 4$ be the events that a box with $2$, $3$, or $4$ flavors, respectively, is selected.  Then the probability of selecting a box with grape-flavored jellybeans is 
$$\Pr(G) = \Pr(2)\Pr(G \mid 2) + \Pr(3)\Pr(G \mid 3) + \Pr(4)\Pr(G \mid 4)$$
Notice that we add since the three events are mutually exclusive.

We are told that one third of the boxes have two flavors, one third of the boxes have three flavors, and one third of the boxes have four flavors.  Therefore,
$$\Pr(2) = \Pr(3) = \Pr(4) = \frac{1}{3}$$

There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select two of the six flavors.  If grape is one of those flavors, there are $\binom{5}{1}$ ways to select the other flavor.  Hence, the probability that grape is one of the flavors in a box containing two flavors is 
$$\Pr(G \mid 2) = \frac{\dbinom{5}{1}}{\dbinom{6}{2}}$$

There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to select three of the six flavors.  If grape is one of those flavors, there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select the other flavors.  Hence, the probability that grape is one of the flavors in a box containing three flavors is 
$$\Pr(G \mid 3) = \frac{\dbinom{5}{2}}{\dbinom{6}{3}}$$

There are $\binom{6}{4}$ ways to select four of the six flavors.  If grape is one of those flavors, there are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to select the other flavors.  Hence, the probability that grape is one of the flavors in a box containing four flavors is 
$$\Pr(G \mid 4) = \frac{\dbinom{5}{3}}{\dbinom{6}{4}}$$

Hence, 
\begin{align*}
Pr(G) & = \Pr(2)\Pr(G \mid 2) + \Pr(3)\Pr(G \mid 3) + \Pr(4)\Pr(G \mid 4)\\
      & = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{5}{1}}{\dbinom{6}{2}} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{5}{2}}{\dbinom{6}{3}} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{5}{3}}{\dbinom{6}{4}}\\
      & = \frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{\dbinom{5}{1}}{\dbinom{6}{2}} + \frac{\dbinom{5}{2}}{\dbinom{6}{3}} + \frac{\dbinom{5}{3}}{\dbinom{6}{4}}\right]\\
      & = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{5}{15} + \frac{10}{20} + \frac{10}{15}\right)\\
      & = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3}\right)\\
      & = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{2}\\
      & = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
Compare this result with lulu's calculation in the comments.